# Creating a matrix using STL vector

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, stl

I want to create a matrix using "vector":

```
vector < vector <int> > Mat;
```

The problem is, when I run this code:

```
int i ,j;
    for(i = 1  ; i <= 5 ; ++i)
    for(j = 1 ; j <= 5 ; ++j)
        Mat[i][j] = 0;
```

I would get a pretty nasty error. How can I fix that?

I do NOT want to read the matrix like this:

```
for(i = 1  ; i <= 5 ; ++i)
    for(j = 1 ; j <= 5 ; ++j)
        M[i].push_back(0);
```

Answer (score 7):

When you're creating your vectors this way, they have a dimension of 0. You have to initialize them with the good size :

```
vector < vector <int> > Mat(6, std::vector<int>(6));
```

By the way, adding a 0 in the second vector initialization will ensure it will be filled with 0 :

```
vector < vector <int> > Mat(6, std::vector<int>(6, 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create a vector it starts off empty unless you tell it what the size should be. If the vector is empty then you cannot use `[]` as it doesn't do any range checking and will not grow the vector.  That leaves you with two options, use `push_back()` or supply a size to the vector when you create it.  For instance we could use

```
const int matrix_size = 5;
auto mat = std::vector<std::vector<int>>(matrix_size, std::vector<int>(matrix_size));
//                                       ^# of rows^                   ^# of cols^
```

Also remember indexes are 0 based in C++.  That means for a vector with 5 elements the valid indexes are `[0, 4]`.  Instead of bothering with the indexes of the vector we can use a [ranged based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to fill the vector like

```
for(auto& row : mat)
    for(auto& col : row)
        std::cin >> col;
```

This will fill every element in the vector from `cin`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I understand.

Comment: @epanicafrate No problem

Answer (score 1):

```
vector < vector <int> > Mat;
```

This creates an empty Mat;

```
vector < vector <int> > Mat (5);
```

will create it with 5 "inside" vectors. The problem still isn't solved, you need to resize the interior vectors as well.

you can do this by: (there are plenty of other better ways)

```
for(int i =0;i<5;i++)
{
  Mat[i].resize(5); // resizing the interior matrices
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to use std::array。

```
std::array< std::array<int, 6>, 6> matirx;
for(auto& row: matrix)
    for(auto& col: row)
        col = 0;
```

Comment: Much better in my opinion would be a generic type that accepts any number of dimensions. Whether you have a typical 4x4 or less typical 3x4, it will work the same. You could even set it up to do matrix math on two matrices with different dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers mention, you need to use the `std::vector` constructor with initial numbers of elements to avoid `push_back`'ing the elements into the vector later. However if you want to initialize your matrix with **zeros**, you don't need to specify the default initializer value, because since C++11 the form `vector(size_type count)` guarantees zeroing out elements of non-class types such as `int`:

```
vector < vector<int> > Mat( 6, vector<int>(6) );
```

This creates a 6x6 int matrix with zeros.